# Replace All Rows in firsttable with Rows from secondtable with Corresponding IDs

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

I have these two tables:

```sql
create table firsttable (id int, speed double precision);
create table secondtable (id int, speed double precision);

insert into firsttable (id) 
values (1), (2);

insert into secondtable (id, speed)
values (1, 12.3), (1, 12.4), (2, 12.43), (2, 11), (2, 13.6), (3,23);
```

I want to update `firsttable`'s speed column with values from `secondtable`

required result:

```
id  speed
1   12.3
1   12.4
2   12.43
2   11
2   13.6
```

```
insert into firsttable(speed)
select speed from secondtable
where id in firsttable.id

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "firsttable"
LINE 4: where id in firsttable.id
```

**EDIT**

The answer by Tushar gives:

```
id  speed
1   null
2   null
1   12.3
1   12.4
2   12.43
2   11
2   13.6
```

**EDIT-2**

I tried:

```sql
INSERT INTO firsttable (id, speed)
SELECT  id,speed 
FROM secondtable 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT id FROM firsttable);

id  speed
1   null
2   null
1   12.3
1   12.4
2   12.43
2   11
2   13.6
3   23
```

But then the firt 2 rows and the last row should not be in the answer (see required answer).

Comment: with a little problem in the expected answer

Comment: that gives 2 rows only.

Comment: Can you check sqlfiddle.com/#!17/04fd3/1  now ?

Comment: same as before.

Comment: Why? You are duplicating data. Why not set up a Foreign Key from `secondtable` to `firsttable`?

Comment: Just use a foreign key.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver how do you mean?

Comment: `create table secondtable (id int references firsttable ON UPDATE CASCADE, speed double precision);`.  Then entries in `secondtable`  would have to have an `id` that matches those in `firsttable`. You would probably want to create another column for the `secondtable` PRIMARY KEY.

Comment: Well, `secondtable` is the table contaning all the complete data. In `firsttable` we have some `id` for which we want to retireve their speed (in the master table). We only have read access to `secondtable`

Comment: Then create a [VIEW](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html) that does that: `create view stbl_1_2 as select * from secondtable where id in (1, 2);`. Or just `select * from secondtable where id in (1, 2);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the description of the desired behavior, it appears that the title should have been *Replace All Rows in Table1 with Rows from Table2 with Corresponding IDs*. The following query will do this:

```
WITH ids AS
       (DELETE FROM firsttable
         WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM secondtable)
         RETURNING id)
INSERT
  INTO firsttable (id, speed)
SELECT id, speed
  FROM secondtable
  WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM ids)
  RETURNING *;
```